# How to update one component from another

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am new in Angular and I am learning it now. I have a problem with updating property in one component from another.
I have container component - `app.component`, and two oders - `create.component` and `list.component`.
I want to create simple string value in `create.component` and then `list.component` should be updated, but with no result. Below I provided some code presenting what I have done.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  myValues: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myValues = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'];
  }

  addValue(evt){
    this.myValues.push(evt);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-create (newValue)="addValue($event)"></app-create>

<br><br>
<app-list [values]="myValues"></app-list>
```

create.component.ts

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html'
})
export class CreateComponent {
  @Output() newValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  value;

  createValue() {
    this.newValue.emit(this.value);
  }
}

create.component.html

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/><button (click)="createValue()">Add</button>
```

list.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-list",
  templateUrl: "./list.component.html"
})
export class ListComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() values;
  public lowercaseValues: string[] = [];

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.values.forEach(v => {
      this.lowercaseValues.push(v.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

list.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let value of lowercaseValues">
  {{value}}
</div>
```

Making values lowercase in `list.component` is just an example of doing something with received data.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: I saw some stackblitz links here and there is minimal reproducible example. I couldn't find how I can post angular code here

Comment: Point me to them so I can help close those with stackblitz links. Hit th edit button on your question to fix your question.

Comment: Try using `this.myValues = [...this.myValues, evt]` instead of `this.myValues.push(evt)`

Comment: I don't think so `this.myValues = [...this.myValues, evt]` will work. Use `this.myValues = [...this.myValues]` extra line as i answered below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the question of change detection since in your case **list.component** property is not updating this change detection is not getting triggered and latest value of **myValues** array in **app.component** is not reflecting in **list.component**. So for triggering change detection, change the reference the of **myValues** array as following:

```
 this.myValues.push(evt);
 this.myValues = [ ...this.myValues ]
```

Second line will actually create a new reference and will assign to existing **myValues** array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that myValues in your case is an array which is a reference. And you want on reference change do something. That is wrong way, actually.

What I recomment you is change your list component and draw the received array of values. See the link to the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eshxvp

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  {{value.toLowerCase()}}
</div>
```